# Phone gap sqlite plugin vs websql

Tags: android, sqlite, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have been working on a simple database application for a small phonegap project. I have successfully implemented a websql database that stores a single table with some basic data. Recently I have been reading that this method is being phased out gradually due to some limitations. There seems to be an alternative using a webkit plugin for phonegap. This interfaces between the sqlite database on the phone and the front end.

So my question boils down to: What is the best practice when developing a database application using phonegap? Which technologies would you suggest? Any help is much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Hi if it is larger database then go for Native sql plugin, if it is small then use HTML 5. HTML database They are fast, flexible and never expire.all of the queries are run via JavaScript, they persist until manually removed. but if the DB size is so large application must hang, so for much larger DB manipulation you can use Native Sql.and HTML 5 db Not ideal for sensitive information like password.

refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6956075/html5-sqlite-vs-native-database-in-case-of-phonegap) may help you.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use a sqlite plugin. I have an application since android 4.0 using websql, and now, on the devices using android 4.4, my application stops working.
Don't commit the same error that I do. Use android native sqlite instead html5 websql.