# PhoneGap mobile App + Database performance improvement

Tags: android, cordova

I am creating mobile application using HTML5 (AngularJS, PhoneGap). For local data storage I am using PhoneGap. My application is kind of account management software which required to store lot of relational data on local db. I deployed the application on mobile using command.

**cordova run android**

I am using following script to data store 
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#Storage

This is working properly but performance is really bad (I having Moto G, Quad Core processor, 1 GB RAM). I fired 3 different select query on local database, and it took almost 2-3 second to process. each 3 table has only 1 rows.

I have seen performance matrices provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6956075/html5-sqlite-vs-native-database-in-case-of-phonegap). But to reduce my overall effort I am thinking of using PhoneGap.

So here are my questions

1. How to improve performance with phoneGap on mobile database?
2. I checked the db file application creating in emulator. Found that it's sqlite db file. The same database gives very good performance on native android application. How?
3. Since I am creating mobile application with local database. How suggestive it is to use phonegap database interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [Cordova SQLite-Plugin](https://github.com/brodysoft/Cordova-SQLitePlugin). It should perform much better for your purposes. Native Android also uses SQLite as database.

Comment: I can be wrong, but I think cordova storage also uses sqlite database (http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#Storage).

Comment: Nope, as stated on your linked page, they use WebSQL, which is another SQL variant.

Comment: I agree to your point but their database creation statement also says "The method creates a new SQL Lite database".

Comment: It does create a Sqlite database. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24449640/difference-between-window-opendatabase-and-window-sqliteplugin-opendatabase) for a similar question asked by myself. For Improving the performance why don't you preload the data in the memory?

Comment: Thanks @frank, that answer my 2nd question. It will be great if you help me with 1st and 3rd questions. Please post your answer in answer section.